# How to loop epic call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, polling, redux-observable, rxjs6

I have following epic:

```
import {
  map,
  catchError,
  switchMap,
  takeUntil,
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  FETCH_JOKES,
  jokesReceived,
  FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED,
  jokesFetchFailed,
} from '../actions/jokes-action';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { of, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const getJokes = () =>
  ajax.getJSON('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?escape=javascript');

const fetchJokesEpic = action$ => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_JOKES),
    switchMap(() =>
      getJokes().pipe(
        map(response => jokesReceived(response)),
        catchError((err, act) => of(jokesFetchFailed(err))),
        takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED)))
      )
    ),
  );
};

export default fetchJokesEpic;
```

whenever the `FETCH_JOKES` is dispatched this epic starts `ajax` call and on success dispatches `jokesReceived` action or on failure `jokesFetchFailed`.

I want to loop it so unless cancelled the endpoint will be called again after previous call will finish (success or failure).

I thought I could use another epic taht will react to `JOKES_RECEIVED` and `FETCH_JOKES_ERROR` actions and then dispatch `FETCH_JOKES` action that should start cricle again.

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import {
  delay,
  map,
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  JOKES_RECEIVED,
  FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED,
  FETCH_JOKES_ERROR,
  fetchJokes,
} from '../actions/jokes-action';

const pollJokes = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(JOKES_RECEIVED, FETCH_JOKES_ERROR, FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED),
    delay(2000),
    map(action => {
      console.log('pollJokes.map', action);
      if(action.type === FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED)
      { 
        console.log("Cancelled")
        return { type: 'POLL_STOPPED' };
      }
      else {
        // loop
        return fetchJokes();
      }
    })
  );
};
export default pollJokes;
```

However this doesnt work when I dispatch `FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED` action. The action stack looks like this:

```
@INIT
FETCH_JOKES
JOKES_RECEIVED
FETCH_JOKES
JOKES_RECEIVED
...
FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED
FETCH_JOKES
JOKES_RECEIVED
POLL_STOPPED
FETCH_JOKES
JOKES_RECEIVED
...
```

I've tried to add `takeUntil` to the `pollJokes` epic but with the same poor results

```
const pollJokes = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(JOKES_RECEIVED, FETCH_JOKES_ERROR, FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED),
    delay(2000),
    map(action => {
      console.log('pollJokes.map', action);
      if(action.type === FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED)
      { 
        console.log("Cancelled")
        return { type: 'POLL_STOPPED' };
      }
      else {
        // loop
        return fetchJokes();
      }
    }),


    takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED)))


  );
};
```

With this apporach the `pollJokes` epic stops working as soon as the `FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED` is dispatched for the first time. Now I know that the epic completed on `takeUntil`.

What can I do to have this "looping" work? I could I guess implement a middleware that will actually invoke `fetchJokes` when `JOKES_RECEIVED` dispatched, but I was searching for a all-rxjs-solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `repeat`, in order to restart your epic, once it get cancelled by `takeUntil`

```
const pollJokes = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(JOKES_RECEIVED, FETCH_JOKES_ERROR, FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED),
    delay(2000),
    map(action => {
      console.log('pollJokes.map', action);
      if(action.type === FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED)
      { 
        console.log("Cancelled")
        return { type: 'POLL_STOPPED' };
      }
      else {
        // loop
        return fetchJokes();
      }
    }),


    takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(FETCH_JOKES_CANCELLED))),
    repeat()

  );
};
```

Comment: Indeed it helped however I'm sure I've tried this:), is there another solution to this problem?